# How to slice a string from a nested list of strings

Tags: python

I have the following input:

```
list_of_strings = [['01abcdefghijklmnoprs00'], ['02abcdefghijklmnoprs55'], ['03abcdefghijklmnoprs'], ['04abcdefghijklmnoprs11'], ['05abcdefghijklmnoprs22']]
idx_row_list =  [[1, 2], [0, 3], [1, 4]]
idx_col_list = [[10, 12], [8, 12], [8, 12]]
slice_length = 4

Output = []
```

I want to select the strings as rows, based on the indexes from idx_row_list[] array.

```
idx_row_list =  [[1, 2], will be row number 1 and 2 and will select the strings: '02abcdefghijklmnoprs55' and '03abcdefghijklmnoprs'
```

*After selection, I need to slice the selected strings at indexes from idx_col_list = [[10, 12].. array.*

*For the line idx_row_list =  [[1, ... I will apply value idx_col_list = [[10,...
with the length given by slice_length = 4 and extract 4 characters from the string.*

```
For string: '02abcdefghijklmnoprs55' I will slice it as: '02abcdefghi   jklm   noprs55' and save 'jklm' 
For string: '03abcdefghijklmnoprs' I will slice it as: '03abcdefghijk   lmno   prs' and save 'lmno'
```

*Input:*

```
list_of_strings = [['01abcdefghijklmnoprs00'], ['02abcdefghijklmnoprs55'], ['03abcdefghijklmnoprs'], ['04abcdefghijklmnoprs11'], ['05abcdefghijklmnoprs22']]

idx_row_list =  [[1, 2], ...]  and idx_col_list = [[10, 12], ...] and slice_length = 4
```

*Output:*

```
Output = [['jklm', 'lmno'], ...]
```

Comment: Yes it can of course be done. [ask]

Comment: Q: Could this be done with list comprehension? A: Probably

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
output = [[list_of_strings[row_idx][0][col_idx+1:col_idx+1+slice_length] for row_idx, col_idx in zip(*idx)] for idx in zip(idx_row_list, idx_col_list)]
```

output:

```
[['jklm', 'lmno'], ['hijk', 'lmno'], ['hijk', 'lmno']]
```